# Windows7.1SDK and v100 compatible?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sdk

Can a client who *must* use VS2010, plattformtoolset v100 in his application use a library which I build with plattformtoolset Windows7.1SDK?

I know the articles on stackoverflow where SDK7.1 is recommended for Visual Studio 2010 Express instead of v100 but if the two should be incompatible then I need a solution where I can build 64bit libraries with v100.

Comment: I know the linked article very well and it is useful but it does not answer my question about compatibility which is:  Can a client who must use v100 in his own project use my library which has been build with plattformtoolset Windows7.1SDK?

Comment: Article edited. Do you still think it is a duplicate question? Why? The linked article does not contain the answer.

Comment: @BoPersson, you have blocked this question and it is not justified. Please review.